# Regex pattern for splitting BEM string into parts (PHP)

Tags: php, regex, bem

I would like to isolate the block, element and modifier parts of a string via PHP regex. The flavour of BEM I'm using is lowercase and hyphenated. For example:

```
this-defines-a-block__this-defines-an-element--this-defines-a-modifier
```

My string is always formatted as the above, so the regex does not need to filter out any invalid BEM, for example, I will never have dirty strings such as:

```
This.defines-a-block__this-Defines-an-ELEMENT--090283
```

Block, Element and Modifier names could contain numbers, so we could have any combination of the following:

```
this-is-block-001__this-is-element-001--modifier-002
```

Finally a modifier is optional so not every string will have one for example:

```
this-is-a-block-001__this-is-an-element
this-is-a-block-002__this-is-an-element--this-is-an-optional-modifier
```

I am looking for some regex to return each section of the BEM markup. Each string will be isolated and sent to the regex individually, not as a group or as multiline strings. The following sent individually:

```
# String 1
block__element--modifier

# String 2
block-one__element-one--modifier-one

# String 3
block-one-big__element-one-big--modifier-one-big

# String 4
block-one-001__element-one-001
```

Would return:

```
# String 1
block
element
modifier

# String 2
block-one
element-one
modifier-one

# String 3
block-one-big
element-one-big
modifier-one-big

# String 4
block-one-001
element-one-001
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use 3 capturing groups and make the third one optional using the `?`

As all 3 groups are lowercase, can contain numbers and use the hyphen as a delimiter you might use a character class `[a-z0-9]`.

You could reuse the pattern for group 1 using `(?1)`

```
\b([a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*)__((?1))(?:--((?1)))?\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` Word boundary
- `(` First capturing group

  - `[a-z0-9]+` Repeat 1+ times what is listed in the character class
  - `(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*` Repeat 0+ times matching `-` and 1+ times what is in the character class
- `)` Close group 1
- `__` Match literally
- `((?1))` Capturing group 2, recurse group 1
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `--` Match literally
  - `((?1))` Capture group 3, recurse group 1
- `)?` Close non capturing group and make it optional
- `\b` Word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/87w9Yx/1)

Or using named groups:

```
\b(?<block>[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*)__(?<element>(?&block))(?:--(?<modifier>(?&block)))?\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/87w9Yx/2)

Comment: Thank you so much, not only for the answer but explaining and breaking down the pattern. There's something about regex that doesn't stick in up there. You've saved me hours to get what I needed done. Really appreciate your help